# parent control doesn't work?

Tags: release-hera

At first: Sorry for my bad English!

Gladly I want to use the parent control-feature in (a fresh installed) elementary OS 5.1 Hera. But when I create a standard-user and configure all restrictions, all the settings for this account seems to have no effect (even after reboot). So, is there a special step to consider or is it already a known problem?